# Alternating Comment Colours using Odd and Even Classes

Tags: php, css, wordpress, comments

I asked this question earlier but had no luck with responses. :(

I have the new WordPress 2.7 Comments Loop, and I know you can simply add .odd and .even to your CSS to get alternating comment colours, which I've done:

```
.odd { background: #ccc; color: #000; }
.even { background: #bbb; color: #000; }
```

However, I have two different backgrounds - a light and a dark one - that the user can choose from the options panel. Therefore I need two different versions of the odd and even classes so I can have different colours for each, as the above background colours look nice against the light background but not so good against the dark one.

But with the 2.7 Comments Loop, the odd and even classes aren't actually there in the code. If they were, I'd have done something like this:

```
$background = get_option('mytheme_background');
if ($background== "option1") { echo '<div class="odd-dark">'; } 
if ($background== "option1") { echo '<div class="even-dark">'; }
if ($background== "option2") { echo '<div class="odd-light">'; } 
if ($background== "option2") { echo '<div class="even-light">'; }
```

So with .odd and .even not actually being there in the code, how can I go about having two different .odd and .even versions in the CSS?

Comment: Add a class to the body-element: `<body class=".... theme-dark" ...>`. You only need to do that once then and can control the color-schemes easily.

Comment: Here's a tip regarding CSS.  You can attach multiple classes to the same element.  Just use a space separated list.  For example you can define an odd, even, light and dark class, then use class="odd light", class="even dark" etc.  This can make for more concise and flexible CSS and works with all current browsers.  Also the latest browsers all support n-th child for styling odd and even rows without explicitly marking them as such with a class.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**:

```
$background = get_option('mytheme_background');
// no more - between class names to use specializations of odd/even in CSS
if ($background== "option1") { echo '<div class="odd dark">'; } 
if ($background== "option1") { echo '<div class="even dark">'; }
if ($background== "option2") { echo '<div class="odd light">'; } 
if ($background== "option2") { echo '<div class="even light">'; }
```

**AND CSS**:

```
/* now specialize 2 variants for each type odd/even * dark/light */
.odd.light { background: #ccc; color: #000; }
.even.light { background: #bbb; color: #000; }
.odd.dark { background: #ccc; color: #000; }
.even.dark { background: #bbb; color: #000; }
```

**Try this**.

Comment: Where in the comments.php should I put that php code? I've tried putting it below "if ( have_comments() ) :" but it doesn't work so I presume this is the wrong place for the code.

Comment: @EmilyHarris I thought you just needed it working right... as in had it working wrong and then it became right. It's complicated. You need to study WordPress a bit. It's easy for a flat comment structure but if you have the comments threaded, it's a different bowl of fish. Consider going to wordpress.stackexchange.com, paste some code in your comments.php there and have them look at it. I smell a beginner and even if I told you how to do it, I'm not sure you'd get it... and it's very difficult without your theme's comments code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes in conjunction:

```
echo '<div class="even option1">';
echo '<div class="even option2">';
echo '<div class="odd option1">';
echo '<div class="odd option2">';
```

In the CSS file, you specify:

```
.option1.even { background-color: #bbb; color: black; }
.option1.odd { background-color: #ccc; color: black; }
.option2.even { background-color: #222; color: snow; }
.option2.odd { background-color: #444; color: white; }
```

Alternatively, you can apply a CSS class `option1` to your `body` element. This is especially useful if you otherwise had to markup many elements with `class="option1 …"`:

```
<body class="option1">
    <div class="even">…</div>
</body>
```

In CSS:

```
body.option1 .even { /* … */ }
```

And so on. Note there is a space between `option1` and `.even`.

Comment: @Claudrian He’s represented by the black color ;-)